# Coding a CSS layout for a web game scoreboard

Tags: html, css

I would like some suggestions on how to code a game scoreboard in CSS to look like the attached reference drawing. The "Player 1" and "Player 2" are centered above each score box, and all elements are centered in the scoreboard container.

[image: Scoreboard Layout Reference]

Comment: How would you like the design to behave at different screen sizes or on resize?

Comment: Also, how many digits long is the maximum score?

Comment: The maximum score is 64. The scorebord should maintain this layout, that is, Player 1 and 2 are always side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.score-board {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}
.player {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.player h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.score-box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #2CB3C9;
}
```

```html
<div class="score-board">
  <div class="player">
    <h4>Player 1</h4>
    <div class="score-box">
      15
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <h4>Player 2</h4>
    <div class="score-box">
      10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Player 2's score may fall below Player 1's at small enough sizes (that is, on small devices or any other case where the scoreboard might shrink). If this is not the desired functionality, you may want to handle some type of scaling based on the viewport size.